# SQL Constraint of the first letter being upper case

Tags: sql, constraints

```
ALTER TABLE info
ADD CONSTRAINT uppercase 
CHECK (password = UPPER(substr(password, 1 ,1 )));
```

I am curious to why my constraint doesnt work? First time trying to write a constraint, so bear with me here.

Comment: Obvious problem is that you compare 1 character with the whole string, this would only be true for strings of a single character. What RDBMS? What case sensitivity and or collation options are you using? Why are you storing passwords in plain text and enforcing that they start with a capital?

Comment: Unrelated but if the case of the password's first letter matters to you, it seems like you're not encrypting or hashing your passwords. You should be. Preferably hashing (and salting) your passwords.

Comment: I figured it out. That is a good question though and will remember to never store the password.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using MySQL, it doesn't work because constraints are not enforced.  In some other databases, the default collation for `=` has upper and lower case being the same.  And, whatever the default collation, it might be changed for your database.

One way you can readily do this:

```
ALTER TABLE info
    ADD CONSTRAINT uppercase CHECK (ASCII(LEFT(password, 1)) BETWEEN ASCII('A') and ASCII('Z'));
```

That said, in most cases, passwords should *not* be stored in an unencrypted way in the database.  This is very dangerous.  You can encrypt the password at the database layer.  I think it is even better to do encryption at the client layer, so the the free-text password doesn't even make it on the network.

Comment: "*In most other databases, the default collation for = has upper and lower case being the same.*" - this is not true (and violates the SQL standard). In (at least) Oracle, Postgres, DB2, Firebird, Informix, Vertica, Teradata, Greenplum, HSQLDB and Apache Derby string comparison is case-sensitive

Comment: Thank you for answering.  I was comparing the whole stirng to just one letter which doesnt make sense.

Comment: +1. Alhough there's a very valid case for encrypting on both sides so that neither side sees both the raw and final form. @user3716005 As long as the same routine is done at creation of password and login matching, it won't create any problems for matching (not that Gordon implied it would). Apologies to the OP but restrictions at specific positions are silly because every user knows that that specific position has that restriction (it's better, instead, to require a capital letter in the string). While most users will be lazy, attackers don't know if the string is String,sTring,strinG,etc.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I clarified that statement.